# Accessing an application file while implementing a library

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

I want to make restrictions in my library with tokens. The user will be available to implement the library in an application only with the token. Generate the token as a file which they have to put inside the application module. Now while syncing Gradle file the library has to access the token from the application module and to store the token in library resources while generating **value.xml** file.

It's something similar as Google Firebase Servis, where Google generate **google_service.json** file and we have to put them inside an application module. On synchronization Gradle file they parse that json and store the data inside **value.xml** resources.

In Gradle file, they **apply plugin**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't know is it the reason how they parse the JSON file but looks like. Also, I don't have to much experience in work with Gradle Plugins. There is some documentation that I have read how to write a plugin. [Writing Gradle Plugins](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-plugins/)

Question on the end. Is it possible for this kind of restriction and accessing the file on this way with the Gradle Plugin?